# Invalid Syntax on Variable

Tags: python

```
Avocado=eval(input("Enter amount of Avocadoes"))
if Avocado<=10:1.50*Avocado
else Avocado>=11:0.89*Avocado
print ("The price is", int(Avocado))
```

Im trying to write a program that will price Avocado's at one price if at 10 or less and another price for 11 or more.

I get my syntax error on line 3 Avocado, I am slightly confused because if it was the formula i would of expected to get the error in line 2 instead.

Would the solution be something like this?

```
if Avocado<=10=1.50*Avocado
else Avocado>=11=0.89*Avocado
```

I know that also gets a syntax error and i feel like thats going backwards.

Comment: Don't use `eval`; you are expecting an `int` (or possibly a `float`), so use that instead.

Comment: You have to reassign the variable like Avocado = Avocado*1.5 and the same for other value and you need elif instead of else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a separate variable to store the total price of the given amount of avocados.

```
avocados = int(input("Enter amount of avocados"))

if avocados <= 10:
    cost = 1.5 * avocados
else:
    cost = 0.89 * avocados

# Or more tersely
# cost = avocados * (1.5 if avocados <= 10 else 0.89)

print("The price is ${}".format(cost))
```

---

In general, try to avoid using `float` to represent money. (You don't want rounding errors to lose money or cheat someone out of money.) Represent currency amounts as an integer number of cents (or whatever your smallest unit of currency is), and convert to dollars and cents for display only.

```
cost = avocados * (150 if avocados <= 10 else 89)

print("The price is ${}.{}".format(*divmod(cost, 100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were not even writing it in python.
Hmm....there's too much to say.

```
while True:
    try:
        avocado = int(input("Enter amount of avocadoes: "))
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Please input a number")
        continue

if avocado < 10:
    avocado = 1.50*avocado
else:
    avocado = 0.89*avocado
print("The price is", int(avocado))
```